# How can I make the ImageEditor's zoomToFit work so that I use the available screen space?

Tags: sapui5

I want to use a `sap.suite.ui.commons.imageeditor.ImageEditor` control inside a `sap.m.WizardStep`.
After loading the image I want to use the `zoomToFit` method of the control to resize the image and use a maximum of the available screen space: 100% width and the height maximized to what's left available in the `WizardStep` without adding scroll bars.

I created a sample to show the challenge: https://plnkr.co/edit/9GhXbOzuIqP6VxqS?preview

Comment: A wizard can consist of multiple steps. So your second requirement (without adding scrollbars) might not be achievable.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your comment. You can consider "without scrollbars" is an optional requirement, but since I am using the experimental `renderMode='Page'`, the steps are shown page by page and thus maybe there is a way to not have scrollbars.

Comment: The issue is that the wizard step has no `100%` height unlike other parent elements. You could fix it with `height: 100%` in custom CSS but that creates a vertical scrollbar and is not really future-proof. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I do wish to avoid scrollbars unless the content would exceed the available space. Good to know it's the WizardStep that is missing the height spec. I have described my current workaround here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3413

Comment: So this is kind of a monkey patch: https://embed.plnkr.co/9NIF3CdEaN1d7p8B?show=controller%2FApp.controller.js,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff Let me know if this is acceptable for you.

Comment: That's a clever monkey patch that I'll gladly adopt. Thanks @BoghyonHoffmann